# List contains Map needs to swap the value in one to many relationship

Tags: java, list, collections

We have below list object that contains map:

```
[
  {groupname="HR", username="101"},
  {groupname="Admin", username="101"}, 
  {groupname="local", username="102"}, 
  {groupname="local", username="101"}, 
  {groupname="HR", username="102"}, 
  {groupname="Finance", username="101"}
]
```

we want to convert in below format:

```
[
  {groupname=["HR","Admin","Finance","local"], username="101"},
  {groupname=["local","HR"], username="102"}
]
```

I tried with code

```
     for(Object map : list)
     {
         Map entyMap =(Map) map;
        String username1= (String)entyMap.get("username");
        System.out.println("username1 : " + username1 );
        //for(String userName: map.keySet()){
            for(Object map1 : list)
            {
                Map entyMap1 =(Map) map1;
             if (entyMap1.containsValue(username1))
             {
                groupList.add(entyMap1.get("groupname"));
                System.out.println(" grouplist: " + groupList );
             }
            } 
        //}
        Map newMap = new HashMap();
        newMap.put("username",username1);
        newMap.put("groupname",groupList);
         System.out.println(" newMap value: " + newMap );
         mapSet.add(newMap);
          System.out.println(" list Value : " + mapSet );
        groupList.clear();
     }
```

if anyone has any handy code?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you facing any issues with your code? Sorry, but StackOverflow isn't a free coding service.

Comment: yes I added my code...

Comment: 1. You need to create a new `groupList` in each iteration of the outer loop (and not clearing it). 2. It will be nice to check if a given username wasn't already processed. This probably won't change the result tho.

Answer (score 0):

This works. You could also use `groupingBy` in `Collectors`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

  static class RoleMapping {
    String role;
    String userId;

    public RoleMapping(String role, String userId) {
      this.role = role;
      this.userId = userId;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<RoleMapping> roleMapping = new ArrayList();

    roleMapping.add(new RoleMapping("HR", "101"));
    roleMapping.add(new RoleMapping("Admin", "101"));
    roleMapping.add(new RoleMapping("local", "101"));
    roleMapping.add(new RoleMapping("local", "102"));
    roleMapping.add(new RoleMapping("HR", "102"));
    roleMapping.add(new RoleMapping("Finance", "101"));

    Map<String, List<String>> roleMap = new HashMap();
    roleMapping.stream().forEach(entry -> {
      List<String> roles = roleMap.putIfAbsent(entry.userId, new ArrayList());

      roleMap.get(entry.userId).add(entry.role);

    });

    roleMap.keySet().forEach(user -> System.out.println("User [" + user + "] - Roles [" + roleMap.get(user) + "]"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
User [101] - Roles [[HR, Admin, local, Finance]]
User [102] - Roles [[local, HR]]
```

Comment: thanks for your response and your code is working perfect but output is not the one which I asked your map contains data like this {101=[HR, Admin, local, Finance], 102=[local, HR]}

Comment: You wanted `groupNames` to be grouped by `users`. This code brings it in that structure. How the datastructure is printed is another level of detail. If you are looking to print in  protobuf or JSON format then you can use a relevant converter. My understanding is grouping is what you needed. Did you need code to print the data structure in required format too?

Answer (score 0):

```
     for(Object map : list)
     {
         Map entryMap =(Map) map;
        String username1= (String)entryMap.get("username");
        System.out.println("username1 : " + username1 );
        Set groupSet= new HashSet();
            for(Object map1 : list)
            {

                Map entryMap1 =(Map) map1;

             if (entryMap1.containsValue(username1))
             {

                groupSet.add(entryMap1.get("groupname"));
                System.out.println(" groupSet: " + groupSet );
             }
            } 
       if (!groupSet.isEmpty()){
        Map newMap = new HashMap();
        newMap.put("username",username1);
        newMap.put("groupname",groupSet);
         System.out.println(" newMap value: " + newMap );
         mapSet.add(newMap);
          System.out.println(" list Value : " + mapSet );

       }
     }
```